# Not returning correct INT

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out why it returns 1 as the integer when I print the max_user_id the very first time I run this function which exists inside my library. It should be returning 10000. I have also included the users model function as well. Do want to make a point that at the point the model function is ran the first time it is empty.

Library

```
/**
 * Create new user on the site and return some data about it:
 * user_id, username, password, email, new_email_key (if any).
 *
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @return  array
 */
function create_user($username, $email, $password, $first_name, $last_name)
{
    if ((strlen($username) > 0) AND !$this->ci->users->is_username_available($username)) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    } 
    elseif (!$this->ci->users->is_email_available($email)) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $genPassHash = $this->ci->genfunc->GenPassHash($password);

        $max_user_id = $this->ci->users->get_max_users_id();
        echo $max_user_id;

        $user_data = array(
            'username'      => $username,
            'password'      => $genPassHash[0],
            'password2'     => $genPassHash[1],
            'email'         => $email,
            'first_name'    => $first_name,
            'last_name'     => $last_name,
            'new_email_key' => md5(rand().microtime()),
            'user_id'       => $max_user_id,
            'ip_address'    => $this->ci->input->ip_address()
        );

        if ($this->ci->users->create_user($user_data) == FALSE)
        {
            $user_data['user_id'] = $res['user_id'];
            $user_data['password'] = $password;
            unset($user_data['last_ip']);
            return $user_data;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Model:

```
/**
 * Get the max int of users id
 *
 * @return  int
 */
function get_max_users_id()
{
    $this->db->select_max('user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $query->row();
        return $row->user_id +1;
    } 
    else
    {
        return 10000;      
    } 
}
```

Comment: Looks like that `$query->num_rows()` is not larger than zero... .

Comment: are you sure your table is not empty?

Comment: At that point the table is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(blah) FROM bleh;
```

Always returns 1 row. If no rows exist, it returns a row with NULL as a value.

So, you'll need to do:

```
if (!$row->user_id) { return 10000; }
```

Please tell me that you're not using this to do insertions though. What if two users go to get created at the exact same time, and both try to create with ID 7? Auto incrementing fields exist for a reason.

Comment: That's a good point however the odds of that with my system are very very small.

Comment: Also what if the table is empty.

Comment: Even if the odds are very small, it's a very bad programming practice when the problem is very easily avoided. Just use an auto increment column. Or, if you can't do that for some reason, you would need to lock the table to make sure no one else selected the same ID. (Or if you're really confident that it will never happen, just leave it and hope that no user ever gets a rather interesting error :p)

Comment: What do you mean what if the table is empty? With the MAX() thing? Fucntions like MAX always return a row in MySQL. Even if the table is empty. It will just return a row with NULL instead of a numeric max.

Comment: Oh okay well I already have an auto incremented row in this table and since that's the case what should I use instead of MAX when the table is empty.

Comment: @JeffDavidson Actually, the answer is already there. The part with if(!$row->user_id) { return 10000; } checks for null and returns 10000 in that case.

Comment: but you forgot to include if there are rows present in the table.

Comment: @JeffDavidson else return $row->user_id+1;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your select_max('user_id') which generates something like

```
SELECT MAX(user_id) from users;
```

SELECT MAX always returns a row, so your row count is always > 0. It may be null if there are no rows, but you're not checking for that.

Comment: Since it's empty what should I use instead of MAX